# In Android, FB's "Create New Facebook Account" is not calling CallbackManager after creating an account

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

In My Android App, I am allowing users to login using Facebook Account. I have added `FacebookSDK` in my project. All required code set up for `FacebookSDK` is done in my SignInActivity. Everything is working fine except the one.

#### What is working :

Case 1 : User is already logged in FB App.

When user chooses login using FB account, FB App will ask for permission from the user and after that the `CallbackManager` will receive a `onSuccess` callback.

Case 2 : User has a FB account, but user has not logged in FB App.

When user chooses login using FB account, FB App will ask for login details and after successful login, FB App will ask for permission and after that the `CallbackManager` will receive a `onSuccess` callback.

*These two cases are working fine. My App is getting calls back from FB App whenever FB sign in is successful/unsuccessful.*

#### What is not working (The Problem) :

Case 3 : User doesn't have a FB account.

In this, the User chooses login with FB account. Since the user doesn't have a FB account, He will select "Create New Facebook Account" option in FB App. After creating an account, FB App will show User's profile page. At this point It is not calling `CallbackManager` in my Android App.

If the user press back button to close Facebook activity, it will minimize the complete app. From this point by pressing back User can't go back to My Android App.

> I have reproduced the same behavior in one of the e-commerce App.

Anyone have any idea about this?